# Mybatis on h2 database can't insert data

Tags: spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I am use `spring boot v1.4.1.RELEASE` + `mybatis-spring-boot-starter v1.1.1` + `h2database v1.4.192` + `flywaydb v4.0.3` to build a spring boot web application.

here is my yml config part file or datasource config:

`datasource:
      km:  

        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver 

        url: jdbc:h2:mem:km;MODE=MySQL;`

And, when I am use mysql to run my unit test, every unit test was passed. But, when I switch to h2database, the same test was not passed.

The ut code is below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class FollowServiceTest {
    private int HOST_ID = 1;
    private int UID = 100;

    @Autowired
    private FollowService followService;

    @Autowired
    private UserFollowDAO followDAO;

    @Test
    public void testFans() throws Exception {

        UserFollow userFollow = new UserFollow();
        userFollow.setHostId(HOST_ID);
        userFollow.setFollowerId(UID);
        followDAO.insert(userFollow);

        List<UserFollow> fans = followDAO.findByIndexHostId(HOST_ID, 0, 10);

        assertThat("fans is empty", fans, not(empty()));
    }
}
```

UserFollowDAO:

```
public interface UserFollowDAO {
    public static final String COL_ALL = " id, host_id, follower_id, create_time, last_update_time "; 
    public static final String TABLE = " user_follow "; 


    @Select(" select " +
            COL_ALL +
            " from " +
            TABLE +
            " where " +
            "`host_id` = #{hostId} " +
            " and id > #{lastId} " +
            " limit #{count} "
    )
    public List<UserFollow> findByIndexHostId(
            @Param("hostId") int hostId,
            @Param("lastId") int lastId,
            @Param("count") int count
    );

    @Insert(" insert into " + TABLE + " set "
        + " id = #{id}, "
        + " host_id = #{hostId}, "
        + " follower_id = #{followerId}, "
        + " create_time = now(), "
        + " last_update_time = now()")
    public int insert(UserFollow bean);
}
```

Error info:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: fans is empty
Expected: not an empty collection
     but: was <[]>

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at com.hi.hk.api.service.FollowServiceTest.testFans(FollowServiceTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

Here is my solutions that I have try:

1. Change datasource config in yml file from `url: jdbc:h2:mem:km;MODE=MySQL` to `url: jdbc:h2:mem:km;MODE=MySQL;LOCK_MODE=1`. Not work.
2. Delete `@Transactional` and `@Rollback` annotation from ut code. Not work.

What can I do next to solve this problem?

@pau:

Here is part of my `application-unit-test.yml` config file:

`datasource:
  ut: true
  km:  
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver 
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:km;MODE=MySQL`

And, I have change datasource config as you said:

```
@Value("${datasource.ut}")
private boolean isUt;

public static final String SQL_SESSION_FACTORY_NAME = "sessionFactoryKm";
public static final String TX_MANAGER = "txManagerKm";
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

@Bean(name = "datasourceKm")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.km")
public DataSource dataSourceKm() {
    if (isUt){
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
        // Because I am use migration db to execute init sql script, so I haven't set script.
    }
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Here is `flyway` bean:

```
@Bean(name = "KmMigration", initMethod = "migrate")
@Primary
public Flyway flyway() throws SQLException {
    logger.info(("================= start km db migration ================="));
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSourceKm());
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);

    if (flyway.getDataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName().toString().contains("H2")) {
        logger.info(("================= using h2 database to start this app ================="));
        flyway.setLocations("/db/migration/ut/km");
    } else {
        flyway.setLocations("/db/migration/km");
    }

    // different developer environment. might get different checksum,
    //   add the statement to skip the checksum error
    // TODO: Maintain checksum across all developers environment.
    flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
    MigrationVersion baselineVersion = flyway.getBaselineVersion();
    logger.info(baselineVersion.getVersion());

    return flyway;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some bug in mycode:

```
@Insert(" insert into " + TABLE + " set "
        + " id = #{id}, "// this line
        + " host_id = #{hostId}, "
        + " follower_id = #{followerId}, "
        + " create_time = now(), "
        + " last_update_time = now()")
    public int insert(UserFollow bean);
```

This insert method will use value of id in bean, that is 0. So, I can't get right value. when I delete  this line, this unit test is passed.